# Did Valmiki address Rama as the the supreme being when he spoke to him personally in the Uttara Kanda?

Tags: vishnu, rama, valmiki

Logically he should have because he has already narrated how Brahma and others called Rama as Vishnu and Narayana and the supreme being at the end of the war.

Answer (score 3):

Valmiki addressed Rama with the words like Dashrathe, Mahavrata Rama etc. But when Sita went into Patala, Lord Brahma addressed Lord Rama as Vishnu:

Uttarakanda, Sarga 98:

> I would not have reminded thee of this secret but for the present necessity. Do thou now once more remember **thy birth from Vishnu**. By nature, Sita is pure, chaste and ever dependent upon thee. And by virtue of her ascetic dependance upon thee she has gone to the region of Nagas. Thou shalt again meet her in heaven (Vaikuntha). Hear, what I communicate unto thee before the assembly.
>
> [image]

And Sage Valmiki was present there when Lord Brahma said this as at the end of the conversation with Lord Brahma, Lord Rama said to Sage Valmiki:

> O illustrious sir, the Rishis living in Brahmas region have grown desirous of hearing my future history. So let it be taken up next morning.
> [image]

Comment: Are these shlokas from Uttarakanda?

Comment: yes, they r from Uttarakanda.. @Pandya

Comment: Ok. It would be useful if you mention the location of the verse which sarga of Uttarakanda. I found it is Sarga 98, revised your answer

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Verse numbers are visible from the screenshot itself. Are screenshots visible to you? You could've added them yourselves right? Exact location of verse is upto the OP.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Sarga number is required to locate the verse