# Why should the absolute Brahman of Shaiva be Shiva and of Vaishnava be Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, brahman

Absolute Brahman resembles One possibility of Perfection, not all possible Perfections, i.e: He is surely Perfect, but resembles One mode (model) of Perfection.

Absolute Brahman is One.

The Creations (Jivas) are the Many.

There are some Jivas identical to Brahman, but not all Jivas.

Some Jivas are perfect, some aren't but able to be perfected, i.e: integral.

Why we supposed that Brahman is the most perfect entity?, Doesn't He represent only one mode of Perfection?

For me, some Atmans may be of more Perfection  than the mode of Brahman.

So, for Shaiva, why they supposed that Shiva is Brahman. And Vaishnava supposed that Vishnu is Brahman?

Why not Shiva is the most Perfect mode of Perfection, but he is not Brahman?, Why not Vishnu is the most perfect mode of Perfection but he is not Brahman?

It is clear that Brahma is the personified Brahman, and this resembles one mode of Perfection.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37183/16530 Br(A)hma, Vishn(U) and (M)ahesh are personified Triguna manifested Prakriti. Just like in the one sky, a cloud appears and after some time lightening, cloud and lightening appear to different, but sky is one & same, so are different forms given to the one formless God. Even the word Brahman is not truth, its just a finite word, truth is Shanti/peace. hence, vedic prayers end with Om Shanti(Peace). After creation(A)+maintainance(U)+Destruction(M), there is peace. But can we see Peace or write Peace or remember Peace? It can be only experienced.

Comment: @ManuKumar How to say: Destruction (M)?!. This is unpleasant concept in Hinduism!. If you said: fading, dissolution or annihilation all of these words more acceptable than Destruction. I hope we go back to Vedas and try to understand them philologically and hermeneutically.

Comment: Destruction(M) stands for mortal, mritya, maut, maya, matter, material etc.,. You are trying to understanding spirituality through lens of your mind which has good or bad differences, try to understand them with intellect and logically similar to science. Just like science is study of matter, similarly spirituality is study of spirit. Dissolution is same as destruction, death itself is destruction of body and its ego, thats where the spirituality of God is needed for fearlessness-immortality. Death of manifested matter in nature is common for everyone, regardless of one's religion or species.

Comment: @ManuKumar Thanks for explaining (M), could you also explain to me: creation (A) and maintenance (U)?. I would like to say that I am Spiritual, I have passed very beautiful spiritual journey since 2006 until now.

Comment: @ManuKumar  I accept inference only by 100%, I expose testimony to inference, also I expose perception to inference. During inference I use Dialectic. Intuition may also mistakes so I expose it also to inference.

Comment: Creation(A) stands for A, Alif, Alpha, Alakh first letter in most of the religious languages across world. A is also used in negation of any object or expression like apathy, asymmetric in Indro-Aryan languages because Creator cant be expressed with any image or word and the creation appeared from nothingness by a creator in all major popular religions Neti-Neti(not this, not this). Maintenance(U)  is from Upper, Pr(o)duce, Utpati, while Down(matter) is below. Now this up-down is shown as heaven-earth in many religious cultures but in words of spirituality, its Soul(inside) and Body(outside).

Comment: I would just say that you can't understand spirituality in words or books, only experience it, as no words are sufficient to concretize it, thats why symbols and parables are used by messengers of God for common people to follow, highlighting the need of Guru or teacher for serious seekers. But following with mind alone leads to superstitions and hatred for non-followers, similarly too much reasoning also leads to confusion and head muddling loops, one should balance one's mind and intellect in this field as both are expressions of same spirit.

Comment: @ManuKumar Thanks a lot for your comments. I assure you that I have passed a real spiritual experience. I passed a Metaphysical phenomenon called Automatic Writing, 4 times since 2006. Intuition my be delusional, the most accurate way to get confirmed, right information is to expose perception, Intuition and testimony to Inference Using Dialectic.

Comment: Ok, very few go through spiritual experiences about 1 in thousand and it cant be proved in scientific lab made of matter. Like I said in beginning God is actually Peace(Om Shanti), even the word 'Islam' means peace.