# How to reconcile the lakshanas of a siddha from the Vedanta and the tantras?

Tags: brahma, goddess, tantra, kali, tara

In the shabasadhana of the tantra, the sadhaka normally worships Mahavidyas ie devatas like Kali, Tara etc, who are Brahma according to the Tantras. After the sadhaka gets siddhi, he has to remain confined for fifteen days as the 'devata' resides within the body of the siddha. If he hears songs, he becomes deaf. If he sees dance, he becomes blind. If he speaks in day time, he becomes dumb. If he enjoys sex, he becomes diseased. After performing many rites on the sixteenth day, he becomes eligible to lead a normal life.

The 'devata' before giving siddhi asks for some bali (sacrifice) like elephent, man etc. The sadhaka has to say:बारान्तरे दास्यामि ie I shall offer you later. On the next day, he has to prepare a doll of elephant or man etc, (whatever was wanted) by powdered rice and offer the bali to that deity.(Ref: Tantrikguru, Nigamananda Saraswati ; Sashtramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana by Upendrakumar Das,vol 2)

On the otherhand, the Upanishads says that one who at the end of brahmavichara sees God  दृष्टे परावरे (as in the famous verse of the Kathopanishad) or Brahma becomes free from all karmas and he becomes full of bliss and free from fear for ever like  न विभेति कदाचनः &  कुतश्चनः.

How can these two different descriptions of illumined souls be reconciled? God is one and so both should yield identical results!More precisely, is a tantrasiddha permanently relieved from tritapajwala as is a jnanamarga or bhaktimarga siddha?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was Tantric upasana (Vamachara) a relatively new concept (or) in existence in ancient India also?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9038/was-tantric-upasana-vamachara-a-relatively-new-concept-or-in-existence-in-an)

Comment: @RakeshJoshi i didnt find the differences in qualities of siddhas in that

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88683/discussion-on-question-by-partha-banerjee-how-to-reconcile-the-lakshanas-of-a-si).

Comment: Tantra and Vedanta are two different paths for realization. The god they speak of is also different. Hence there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by the following sloka of the Kaula-Marga-Rahasya (page 91)
where Sri BhagavAn says:

> tAntrikAnam aham devi na labhyo avyavadhAnatah/kAlena devatA prAptir dvAreNa eva aham astike/ labhyo vedaikanisthanAm aham avyvadhAnatah// meaning : **Tantriks are fallen from the vedic path and so can not attain me directly.They attain me through getting grace of a DevatA form and are liberated gradually.Only those who walk sincerely on the vedic path get me quickly.**

So siddhi of Tantrasadhana is not the same as the Brahmopolabdhi mentioned in the Upanishads. Tantriks reach the final goal in a gradual way.

**UPDATE**

What has been referred to above seems to be true only for the DevatA-sadhnAs and NOT for Ishvara-sAdhAna.Many saints got the highest liberation using the Tantrik methods also.In fact the 'Divya-KaulapAchara' is used by the aspirants who are at the highest level. So the above must not be applicable for them.